# How to change time in text file and edit Text

Tags: python

I have Text File and this file has many line with same format.

> $GPRMC,**073305.00**,A,1349.172466,N,10030.889330,E,1.8,159.3,030419,1.1,W,A*29
>       $GPRMC,**073306.00**,A,1349.172245,N,10030.889379,E,1.1,159.2,030419,1.1,W,A*28
>       $GPRMC,**073307.00**,A,1349.172447,N,10030.889320,E,0.0,159.5,030419,1.1,W,A*26
>       $GPRMC,**073308.00**,A,1349.172618,N,10030.889166,E,0.9,159.5,030419,1.1,W,A*28
>       $GPRMC,**073309.00**,A,1349.172773,N,9930.888557,E,3.1,284.6,030419,1.1,W,A*29
>       $GPRMC,**073310.00**,A,1349.173136,N,9830.887477,E,3.8,284.6,030419,1.1,W,A*22
>       $GPRMC,**073311.00**,A,1349.173632,N,10130.886056,E,5.4,282.7,030419,1.1,W,A*2B
>       $GPRMC,**073312.00**,A,1349.174155,N,9530.884440,E,5.0,286.9,030419,1.1,W,A*26

I want to change Time(Bold number **hhmmss.ms**) by **+7 hours** and edit and remove some text.

The result I think like this.

> Time **14**3305.00 Lat 1349.172466 N Lon 10030.889330 E
>
> Time **14**3306.00 Lat 1349.172245 N Lon 10030.889379 E
>
> Time **14**3307.00 Lat 1349.172447 N Lon 10030.889320 E
>
> Time **14**3308.00 Lat 1349.172618 N Lon 10030.889166 E
>
> Time **14**3309.00 Lat 1349.172773 N Lon 9930.888557 E
>
> Time **14**3310.00 Lat 1349.173136 N Lon 9830.887477 E
>
> Time **14**3311.00 Lat 1349.173632 N Lon 10130.886056 E
>
> Time **14**3312.00 Lat 1349.174155 N Lon 9530.884440 E

I start adapt this code from google to remove text.

```
# Open the file as read
f = open("/home/pi/GPS.TXT/gpsdata.2019-05-09_21:54.txt", "r+")
# Create an array to hold write data
new_file = []
# Loop the file line by line
for line in f:
# Split A,B on , and use first position [0], aka A, then add to the new array
  only_a = line.split(",")
# Add
new_file.append(only_a[1])
new_file.append(only_a[3])
new_file.append(only_a[4])
new_file.append(only_a[5])
new_file.append(only_a[6])
# Open the file as Write, loop the new array and write with a newline
with open("/home/pi/GPS.TXT/gpsdata.2019-05-09_21:54.txt", "w+") as f:
 for i in new_file:
  f.write(i+"\n")
```

but it add new line every text. like this.

> 145510.00
>
> 1357.157766
>
> N
>
> 10036.988721
>
> E
>
> 145511.00
>
> 1357.157766
>
> N
>
> 10036.988722
>
> E
>
> 145512.00
>
> 1357.157766
>
> N
>
> 10036.988721
>
> E
>
> 145513.00
>
> 1357.157766
>
> N
>
> 10036.988721
>
> E

How I change time and edit this text.
I don't know what to do. I'm a newbie in python.
Where I should start in this code? Change time, remove text or edit text?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're writing to the file:

```
for i in new_file:
  f.write(i+"\n")
```

is taking current index from `new_data` and writing it to the file as new line, thus your formating happens.

To fix that, you need to format the line before write, so change your `# Add` block to something like this:

```py
# don't add column by column to a dict; format a string to your liking and add it instead.
new_file.append("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}".format(only_a[1], only_a[3], only_a[4], only_a[5], only_a[6]
```

About the offseting to 7 hours, how is that time coded? I'm guessing its a `%H%M%S.%f` format (hours, minutes, seconds, milis) so you can do something like this using `datetime` and `timedelta`:

```py
# import these
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# get time from your data and convert it to datetime object
current_dt = datetime.strptime(only_a[1], '%H%M%S.%f')
# add 7 hours
future_dt = current_dt + timedelta(hours=7)
```

once you do this, you can simply replace `only_a1[1]` from my code with `future_dt.strftime("%H%M%S.%f")` and it should work.

Edit: complete solution, since you have issues figuring it out

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Open the file as read
f = open("/home/pi/GPS.TXT/gpsdata.2019-05-09_21:54.txt", "r+")

# Create an array to hold write data
new_file = []

# Loop the file line by line
for line in f:
    # Split A,B on , and use first position [0], aka A, then add to the new array
    only_a = line.split(",")

    # parse the data for first column, it's a specific case
    current_dt = datetime.strptime(only_a[1],'%H%M%S.%f')
    future_dt = current_dt + timedelta(hours=7)

    # Add to write list
    new_file.append("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}".format(future_dt.strftime('%H%M%S.%f'), only_a[3], only_a[4], only_a[5], only_a[6]))

# Formating loo done, now open output file and write there.
# Open the file as Write, loop the new array and write with a newline
with open("/home/pi/text1.txt", "w+") as f:
    for i in new_file:
        f.write(i+"\n")
```

Comment: I'll try this. When finished I'll tell you the result. Thankyou

Comment: When I should insert text(Time,Lat,Lon)? Before or after linesplit or change time?

Comment: You need to do all text processing before you've formated the string, and format string and add it to the list before you start writing.

Comment: I try new_file.append("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}".format(only_a[1], only_a[3], only_a[4], only_a[5], only_a[6])) But It write file just one line in new format(last line from Original file). Why?

Comment: You need to append data in the loop, if you don't it will add only last line.

Comment: I answer my code In this topic. You say "need to append in the loop" -->> Is this code [new_file.append("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}".format(future_dt, only_a[3], only_a[4], only_a[5], only_a[6]))]  OR this [for i in new_file:
   f.write(i+"\n") ]

Comment: I have a last question. How can I use this program in linux terminal.
with single command.(sudo python edit.py gpsdata.2019-05-09_21:54.txt > edit1.txt)

Comment: OK!!! This program work. I use import sys ,filename = sys.argv[1] and f = open(filename, "r+"). Thankyou very much. I don't have any words to say. This is my thesis. But it not about my major I study. Thankyou again.

Answer (score 0):

Now I Try This.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# Open the file as read
f = open("/home/pi/GPS.TXT/gpsdata.2019-05-09_21:54.txt", "r+")
# Create an array to hold write data
new_file = []
# Loop the file line by line
  for line in f:
# Split A,B on , and use first position [0], aka A, then add to the new array
 only_a = line.split(",")
current_dt = datetime.strptime(only_a[1],'%H%M%S.%f')
future_dt = current_dt + timedelta(hours=7)
# Add
new_file.append("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}".format(future_dt, only_a[3], only_a[4], only_a[5], only_a[6]))
# Open the file as Write, loop the new array and write with a newline
with open("/home/pi/text1.txt", "w+") as f:
  for i in new_file:
   f.write(i+"\n")
```

and Output is

> 1900-01-01 21:56:48 1357.157782 N 10036.988713 E

Just last line(I'll try in loop)
It add Date in front of time. But Date is not current day.
How should I do?